# How to set the name of a file in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, download, client-side

(This title may not be clear but whatever you read here is a refinement trying to get past the "quality standards" script, which seem to be a lot stricter based on the tags chosen)

On the client side is there any way in jquery to set the name of the file downloaded?

lets say on my server the file is stored as `QXYZO123` , but the file is really information.xls , a spreadsheet. Even the hyperlink says information.xls as I have information linking the random file name to the original file name.

When the user clicks on the link, by default it will try to download the file name as stored on the server, QXYZO123, but I want it instead to say information.xls , how can I set this to suggest the file name to save as?

I call it a suggestion because based on the user's browser settings, it will either auto download with my filename suggestion or ask the user where to download and save it, with the filename suggestion

Comment: You can't do that, but it would be trivial to change the filename to something else on the serverside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no setting file properties from JQuery directly. JQuery means some Javascript codes and Javascript is a client side script language. This means you can do something, only on client side, not on server side.

But there is some indirect methods to do this. First of all, only way to do this is setting the file name on server side. It depends on what language you are using on server side. Depens on server side language,  You can write your own download web api. Pass the file name as a request parameter to your api and let it give you the file with your customized file name. I don't know what language you are using on server side but I prepared a serverside code with node.js that accepts customized file name in 'GET' request as parameter.

```
var sys = require ('sys'),
url = require('url'),
http = require('http'),
qs = require('querystring');
var path = require('path');
var mime = require('mime');
var fs = require('fs');

var server=http.createServer(

function (request, response) {

      if(request.method=='GET') {
        var filePath='path_to_your_file_in_your_server_file_system';
        var filestream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
        var url_parts = url.parse(request.url,true);
        console.log(url_parts);
        var fileName= url_parts.query.fileName; //Taking your customized file name from GET request parameters.
        if(!fileName)
        {
            fileName=path.basename(filePath);
        }

        var mimetype = mime.lookup(filePath);
        response.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
        response.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);
        filestream.pipe(response);


        response.writeHead( 200 );

        response.end();
    }               
}
);

server.listen( 9080 );
```

When you run this server code with node.js you can get file with your customized file name from the url which  `localhost:9080?fileName=yourCustomizedFileName`. As you see we are giving the fileName 'GET' request parameter in url. You can use javascript windows.location or something else to get the file with your customized file name on client side Javascript code.
Don't let the node.js code make you confused. The point of the solution is writing a downloading api which takes fileName parameter from 'GET' request, to send the file with this name to clients.

You can apply this node.js code for your server side language or research how to apply it. Probably, It won't be hard to find and apply it.